# Multiple Conditions not working in "if"

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I am using multiple conditions in if, please see the code below;

```
if (strpos(serialize($row['pirority']),"P1")!==false &&
    strpos(serialize($row['product']),"WFS")!==false) 
    { $wfsp1++; }
```

If i add another condition it doesn't work;

```
if (strpos(serialize($row['pirority']),"P1")!==false &&
    strpos(serialize($row['product']),"WFS")!==false) ||
    strpos(serialize($row['product']),"DayEnd")!==false) 
    { $wfsp1++; }
```

Can any one please guide me, what could be the reason?

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax error.Try this

```
if (strpos(serialize($row['pirority']),"P1")!==false &&
    strpos(serialize($row['product']),"WFS")!==false ||   //extra parenthesis was given
    strpos(serialize($row['product']),"DayEnd")!==false) 
    { $wfsp1++; }
```